# Динамическое подключение библиотеки C++ Linux/Unix

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, library

Подскажите пожалуйста не могу подключить библиотеку libcurl на linux, при подключении библиотеки требует библиотеку libssh, она находится в той-же папке, но программа ее не находит...

> libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> curl = dlopen("./libcurl.so", RTLD_LAZY);

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а при чем здесь UNIX?

Comment: А зачем вам руками делать `dlopen`? Просто слинковаться с библиотекой не вариант?

Comment: А на Linux библиотеки не подгружаются из папки исполняемого файла сами по себе. Для этого надо сильно постараться и работать все равно будет ненадежно. Если хотите таскать библиотеки вместе с приложением, то создавайте докер образ или snap пакет, и запускайте его в виртуальном окружении.

Comment: @user7860670, это шутка такая про докеры-шмокеры?

Comment: А не совсем понимаю комментарии так как даже на Juna не факт что тяну, но! Я хочу что программа работала как chrome из под коробки, будь то deb пакет или просто *.tar.gz архив, без установки сторонних пакетов...

Comment: По-этому хочу использовать dl для динамического подключения библиотек, что-бы обеспечить поддержку на большинстве систем linux/

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, пожалуйста можно ссылку на мануал или подробное объяснение, я слышал про -rpath, там указывается путь поиска для dl (dynamic lib), но не могу его нормально указать, может ошибаюсь....

Comment: curl = dlopen("./libssh2.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL);
Выдает туже ошибку. 
Или, curl = dlopen("./libssh2.so.1", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL);

Comment: Можете рассказать, в чем сама задача? Обычно библиотеки не тягают в папку с экзешником, а оставляют в системных папках, где они обнаруживаются автоматически.

Comment: вероятно, настала пора узнать про [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) вообще и специальный путь в нём `$ORIGIN` в частности. в общем, добро пожаловать в [чудесный и ужасный мир разделяемых библиотек](https://habr.com/ru/post/220961/).

Answer (score 0):

проговорю проблему более формально: вам надо загрузить свою библиотеку (1), которой для работы требуется другая библиотека (2), не установленная в системе, но подложенная вами в тот же каталог, что и первая (библиотека).

вообще правильный путь заключается в пересборке библиотеки (1) с указанем в [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) специального пути `$ORIGIN`. цитата из man-страницы динамического загрузчика `ld.so` (`$ man 8 ld.so`):

```
$ORIGIN (or equivalently ${ORIGIN})
      This expands to the directory containing the program  or  shared
      object.   Thus,  an  application located in somedir/app could be
      compiled with

          gcc -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../lib'

      so that it finds an associated shared object in  somedir/lib  no
      matter  where  somedir  is  located  in the directory hierarchy.
      This facilitates the creation of "turn-key" applications that do
      not  need  to be installed into special directories, but can in‐
      stead be unpacked into any directory and still  find  their  own
      shared objects.
```

---

но при острой необходимости можно воспользоваться и переменной окружения `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, передав в ней путь, где находятся обе библиотеки.

наглядная демонстрация работоспособности:

```
$ ldd $(which curl) | grep libcurl
  libcurl.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f2a29a2c000)
$ readlink -f /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.4.0
$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.4.0 | grep libssh
  libssh2.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh2.so.1 (0x00007f5a31ffd000)
$ readlink -f /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh2.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh2.so.1.0.1
```

складываем обе библиотеки в какой-нибудь каталог:

```
$ mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.4.0 /tmp/libcurl.so.4
$ mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh2.so.1.0.1 /tmp/libssh2.so.1
```

пробуем воспользоваться библиотеками. естественно, неудачно:

```
$ curl --version
curl: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

а теперь попробуем с `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. работает:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp curl --version
curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.52.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2l zlib/1.2.8 libidn2/0.16 libpsl/0.17.0 (+libidn2/0.16) libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.18.1 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL
```

Comment: Еяпп, динамические разделяемые библиотеки грузятся по умолчанию из того же каталога, что и основной исполняемый файл безо всякой магии и дополнительных настроек.